# automatically send stdin to interactive bash script

Tags: bash, interactive

I have a compiled program which i run from the shell; as i run it, it asks me for an input file in stdin. I want to run that program in a bash loop, with predefined input file, such as

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
    input.txt | ./myscript
done
```

but of course this won't work. How can I achieve that? I cannot edit the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
    ./myscript < input.txt
done
```

Pipes (`|`) are *inter-process*. That is, they stream between processes. What you're looking for is [file redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (e.g. `<`, `>` etc.)

> Redirection simply means capturing output from a file, command,
>   program, script, or even code block within a script and sending it as
>   input to another file, command, program, or script.

You may see `cat` used for this e.g. `cat file | mycommand`. Given the above, this usage is redundant and often the winner of a '[Useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)' award.

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself well. the program starts running, THEN, after some internal work, he asks me for input. So your way does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
./myscript < input.txt
```

to send content of `input.txt` on `stdin` of `myscript`

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself well. the program starts running, THEN, after some internal work, he asks me for input. So your way does not work for me.

Comment: Which program asks for input? Is it `myscript` or your compiled program? Can youst your complete script so that I can suggest.

Comment: It is a compiled FORTRAN program; i do not have the source code. Anyway I may have found a solution by making use of `expect`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like `myscript` *prompts* for a file name and you want to always respond with `input.txt`. Did you try this?

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
    echo input.txt | ./myscript
done
```

You might want to just try this first:

```
echo input.txt | ./myscript
```

just in case.